# Get mode (most often) value in Spark column with groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mode, sparkr

I have a SparkR `DataFrame` and I want to get the mode (most often) `value` for each unique `name`. How can I do this? There doesn't seem to be a built-in `mode` function. Either a SparkR or PySpark solution will do.

```r
# Create DF
df <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "Thomas", "Thomas", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill"),
  value = c(5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 7))
DF <- createDataFrame(df)

name   | value
-----------------
Thomas |  5
Thomas |  5
Thomas |  4
Bill   |  3
Bill   |  3
Bill   |  9

# What I want to get
name   | mode(value)
-----------------
Thomas |   5
Bill   |   3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could achieve that using combination of `.groupBy()` and `window` methods like this:

```
grouped = df.groupBy('name', 'value').count()
window = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(desc("count"))
grouped\
    .withColumn('order', row_number().over(window))\
    .where(col('order') == 1)\
    .show()
```

outputs:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|  name|value|count|order|
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|  Bill|    3|    2|    1|
|Thomas|    5|    2|    1|
+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, @pandaromeo. Can you explain what the `Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy(desc('count'))` does? I'm also having trouble converting this code to SparkR, though the `windowPartitionBy` commands exists there.

Comment: after `groupBy` and `agg` you end up with `count` column. Imagine that you perform `orderBy` on it in ascending order. With `window` You not only sort it but also give it index which enables You to filter out only the ones which interests You. In this case those are `mode (most often) value`. Unfortunately I have no experience with R so I can't translate it to SparkR.

Comment: Actually, this link explains it well: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/vignettes/sparkr-vignettes.Rmd.

Comment: If you want to ignore null values do  `grouped = df.where(df["value"].isNotNull()).groupBy("name", "value").count()`

Answer (score 1):

**Spark 3.4+** has [`mode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#mode) column function.

*PySpark* full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('Thomas', 5),
     ('Thomas', 5),
     ('Thomas', 4),
     ('Bill', 3),
     ('Bill', 3),
     ('Bill', 9)],
    ['name', 'value'])

df.groupBy('name').agg(F.mode('value')).show()
# +------+-----------+
# |  name|mode(value)|
# +------+-----------+
# |Thomas|          5|
# |  Bill|          3|
# +------+-----------+
```

*SparkR* full example:

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "Thomas", "Thomas", "Bill", "Bill", "Bill"),
                 value = c(5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 9))
df <- as.DataFrame(df)

df <- agg(groupBy(df, 'name'), expr("mode(value)"))

showDF(df)
# +------+-----------+
# |  name|mode(value)|
# +------+-----------+
# |Thomas|        5.0|
# |  Bill|        3.0|
# +------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SparkR version of the solution:

```
grouped <- agg(groupBy(df, 'name', 'value'), count=count(df$value))
window <- orderBy(windowPartitionBy("name"), desc(grouped$count))
dfmode <- withColumn(grouped, 'order', over(row_number(), window))
dfmode <- filter(dfmode, dfmode$order==1)
```